# What is the derivative of $|Du|$?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $u:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $u$ is differentiable. What is the derivative of $|Du|$? Is it equal to $\text{div}(Du)$? Here div means the divergence.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Recall that $Du$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. What do you mean by $|Du|$?

Comment: I think $Du$ is a vector; actually it is a gradient vector.

Comment: Typically one write $\nabla u$ for what you are talking about, and our definitions are related by $Du(x_0)(x) = \nabla u(x_0)\cdot x$. (I was wrong, it has dimension $2n$ not $n^2$.) Anyway I guess that means you mean the standard Euclidean norm for $|\nabla u|$ then?

Comment: Yes, it is. Do you know what its derivative is? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to know what is $\nabla|\nabla u|$. First off, there is no reason $|\nabla u|$ should be differentiable, no matter how nice $u$ is. E.g. in one dimension with $u(x) = x^2$, $\nabla u = 2x$ and $|2x|$ is not differentiable, well at least at one point.

Clearly the problem here is the kink of the absolute value function at $0$, so lets just compute $\nabla|\nabla u|$ at points $x$ such that $\nabla u(x) \neq 0$.
At such points, the chain rule will ensure for us that $|\nabla u|$ is differentiable as long as $\nabla u$ is. (Thus we should probably assume $\nabla  u$ is $C^2$ up front, or possibly slightly weaker conditions).

After assuming everything we need to make the calculations go through, we just calculate
$$
\partial_i \left(\sum_j (\partial_ju)^2 \right)^{1/2} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_j (\partial_ju)^2 \right)^{-1/2}\cdot\left(\partial_i\sum_j (\partial_ju)^2 \right)
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2|\nabla u|}\left(\sum_j \partial_i(\partial_ju)^2 \right)
=\frac{1}{2|\nabla u|}\left(\sum_j 2\partial_ju\cdot \partial_i\partial_ju \right)
$$
so
$$
\nabla |\nabla u|= \frac{1}{|\nabla u|} (\nabla u)^{\top}\nabla^2u
$$
where $\nabla^2 u$ is a matrix with $(i,j)$ entry $\partial_i\partial_j u$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Does this derivative have any relation to divergence? This is a small part of my problem, and everything works fine except this one. I need divergence appears somehow.
Thanks, again.

Comment: $\nabla^2 u$ is the matrix with $(i,j)$ entry $\partial_i\partial_j u$. The laplace operator I would write $\nabla \cdot \nabla$. I realize this can be confusing if you are reading wikipedia as the notation is not standardized.